# Create multiple addresses for one crypto wallet

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, wallet

I have an online gambling platform and we want to add payments in cryptocurrencies on that platform. We know that there are platforms that can do that for us (coinspaid, nowpayments, etc.) But we want do to this on our side. Our idea is to save unique wallet addresses for every coin, for every user. In that way, we can know who sent money and we can add balance to that player. But the question is how can we create these unique wallet addresses for different users? I will be thankful if someone can send me some links or explain to me what we should search for to do this. :)

Comment: Not possible since you need to solve DLog problem. If you were able to do that, you already break almost all wallets.

Comment: Every address is a separate wallet, basically. You can make as many wallets as you want. It is your job to send the money to the wallet where you need it.

Comment: @GamerXxx, have you found any solution to your problem?

Comment: @NeerajSharma not really :)

Answer (score 0):

You create 1 wallet per cryto and use a different memo for each customer. That way the memo relates to the customer but all the customers pay to the same wallet address

Comment: Interesting, but what about ethereu m !